# unable to retrieve the JSON data returned from the fetch API call in the middleware of Next.js

Tags: next.js, middleware, next.js13

I am currently working on implementing role-based authentication with JWT using Next.js middleware. In my specific scenario, once a user successfully logs in, a JWT token is generated. I then retrieve the user's data from the endpoint http://localhost:3000/api/me. If the token is available, it returns the user's ID and role (`{"user":{"id":"649eaab9129b600eaccd800a","role":"admin"}}`); otherwise, it returns an unauthorized message `{"message":"Unauthorized"}`.

When a user logs in successfully, I can retrieve their user data by entering the following API endpoint in the browser: http://localhost:3000/api/me. However, when I attempt to retrieve the user data from the middleware, it returns an unauthorized message instead.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "role-based-authentication-with-jwt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.4.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^5.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.2",
    "next": "13.4.9",
    "postcss": "8.4.25",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2"
  }
}
```

**middleware.ts**

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value;
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/me");
  const { user } = await response.json();
  if (!token && !user?.role) {
    if (!request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login")) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
    }
  } else if (
    token &&
    user?.role &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${user?.role}`) &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login")
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/access", request.url));
  } else {
    if (!request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${user?.role}`)) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${user?.role}`, request.url));
    }
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/superadmin/:path*", "/user/:path*", "/login"],
};
```

**api/me/route.ts**

```
import { getUser } from "@/helpers/getUser";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || "";
    if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: "Unauthorized",
        },
        {
          status: 401,
        }
      );
    }
    const user = getUser(request);
    return NextResponse.json({
      user,
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

**helpers/getUser.ts**

```
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";

export const getUser = (request: NextRequest): TokenData => {
  try {
    const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || "";
    const decodedToken: any = verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET!);
    return { id: decodedToken.id, role: decodedToken.role };
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};
```

To facilitate role-based routing, I need to access the user's role from the fetch api in middleware. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this but I would think that a fetch request from middleware do not include cookies automatically as it doesn't come from the browser. I think you need to change to

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/me", {
  credentials: "include" // or "same-origin"
})
```

Alternative, you could send the token as a parameter like

```
const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value;
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/me?token=" + token);
```

and update api with

```
const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || request.nextUrl.searchParams.token;
```

or something similar